# Dynamic viewport with js Cordova or Phonegap Android KitKat 4.4

Tags: cordova, webview, viewport, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using the following code to resize/scaling my app to the screen size of the any device (iOS, Android):

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>App Title</title>
<meta id="Viewport" name="viewport">     
<script src="plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<script src="plugins/main.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      var ww = ( $(window).width() < window.screen.width ) ? $(window).width() : window.screen.width; 
      var mw = 1080;
      var ratio =  ww / mw;
      if( ww < mw){
       $('#Viewport').attr('content', 'initial-scale=' + ratio + ', maximum-scale=' + ratio + ', minimum-scale=' + ratio + ', user-scalable=yes, width=' + ww);
      }else{
       $('#Viewport').attr('content', 'initial-scale=' + ratio + ', maximum-scale=' + ratio + ', minimum-scale=' + ratio + ', user-scalable=yes, width=' + ww);
      }
    }
    });                                             
</script></head>
```

and it works perfectl on iOS and Android to Api lvl 18, stop working on lvl 19 KitKat 4.4.2
I read that: PhoneGap uses Android WebView before KitKat (4.4) but how to make this code work for which I have given ? **looks as if they do not execute js**

or any suggestions other solution ???

Thx for any suggestions

**UPDATE 30.04.2014**

I also setup manualy viewport without js and on Android 4.3 works perfect but on 4.4.2 not working at all - I use Cordova 3.4.0 in Eclipse

Comment: Both the `if( ww < mw )` and the `else` have the same code in them, could this be the issue? Additionally, I have always used `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">` in my apps and it has worked for me in all cases.

Comment: no no this is not the problem :)

and I also tested several times before:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

and it never work.

Comment: Hi, kit kat doesn't use webKit anymore, it uses chromium so there are some inconsistences.

To achieve the same effect for Android 4.4 it looks like using `document.body.style.zoom` works.
For details take a look at [this community.phonegap.com post](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/viewport_changes_on_android_or_pgb#reply_13959613)